# How to Start new Activity from inside Uncaught Exception Handler

Tags: android

In my Android application I need to manage all the uncaught exceptions from my custom Activity class. Now I have a problem here, I unable to start a Activity from inside. There is no exceptions even though the Activity is not starting.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    Context context;
    Throwable throwable;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context=getApplicationContext();
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
                throwable=ex;
                new Thread(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Looper.prepare();

                        builder.setTitle("Warning...!");
                        builder.create();
                        builder.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                finish();

                            }
                        });
                        builder.setPositiveButton("More Details", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Intent intent= new Intent(MyActivity.this,Report.class);
                                intent.putExtra("error", throwable);
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        });
                        builder.setMessage(throwable.getMessage());
                        builder.show();
                        Looper.loop();
                    }
                }.start();  
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to chnage this line

```
startActivity(intent);
```

by

```
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what ive searched, it seems like you cannot start an `Activity` from `UncaughtExceptionHandler`. The maximum you can do is show a `Toast` message.

```
Toast.makeText(app, "Some message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score -1):

This code is working fine with me.

**Note:** it will take `2 seconds` to load new activity after uncaught exception code i have defined.

just put below code in your onCreate method of Activity

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler(){

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000, intent);
        System.exit(2); 
        startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,TargetActivity.class));
    }
    });
```

let me know if you get any trouble regarding this!!

Comment: mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000, intent); what is intent here

Comment: Can you please explain this example a bit more? How will the line below system.exit(2) be called?